# Problems with std::piecewise_constant_distribution and std::vector

Tags: c++, random, c++11, distribution, piecewise

Given a bunch of strings I'm trying to create a program that can mimic a pseudo-random behaviour with weighted distribution based on my input.

So far I came up with this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

#define N 100

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> interval{"Bread", "Castle", "Sun"};
    std::vector<float> weights { 0.40f, 0.50f, 0.10f };
    std::piecewise_constant_distribution<> dist(interval.begin(),
                                                interval.end(),
                                                weights.begin());

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()) ;

    for(int i = 0; i<N;i++)
    {
        std::cout << dist(gen) << "\n";
    }

    return(0);

}
```

But this thing doesn't works and I have no clue why, the usual usage of `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` , according to online examples, it's with `std::arrays`, but I'm trying to implement it using `std::vector`, this is the main difference that I found.

With Clang++ the output of the error is

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/random.tcc:2409:10: error: no matching member function for
      call to 'push_back'
                _M_int.push_back(*__bbegin);
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

but I can't understand it because there is no explicit `.push_back` in my code, I also don't get from what is coming from because debugging a templated class it's a nightmare and I'm just starting with this one.

Anyone having any idea why code doesn't work ?

Comment: @taocp yes, also I have done this inside an IDE and with a command line compiler interface, both with C++11 support, nothing changes.

Comment: where have you seen example with string? it complains because can't operate on strings

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain nowhere, it's simply what I need and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I am refering to your comment: according to online examples, it's with std::arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default result type of `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` is `RealType` (`double` here). It seems like you're trying to choose from 3 `string` options with various weights, but this isn't what `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` is for. It's designed to generate uniform random values from **numeric** intervals with the given weighting. If you modify your example and change `interval` to:

```
std::vector<double> interval {1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20};
```

Everything will compile happily. By the looks of it, you want `std::discrete_distribution`:

```
...

std::vector<std::string> interval{"Bread", "Castle", "Sun"};
std::vector<float> weights { 0.40f, 0.50f, 0.10f };
std::discrete_distribution<> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());

std::mt19937 gen(rd());

for(int i = 0; i<N;i++)
{
    std::cout << interval[dist(gen)] << "\n";
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template< class RealType = double >
class piecewise_constant_distribution;
```

operates on `RealType`, cannot operate on strings. [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution)

> produces random floating-point numbers, which are uniformly
>   distributed within each of the several subintervals [bi, bi+1), each
>   with its own weight wi.

change it to be:

```
std::vector<float> weights { 0.40f, 0.50f, 0.10f };
std::discrete_distribution<> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());

std::mt19937 gen(rd());

for(int i = 0; i<N;i++)
{
    std::cout << interval[dist(gen)] << "\n";
}
```

and you're done.

---

ADVICE:
read messages produced by your friend compiler

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/random:51:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/random.tcc: In instantiation of ‘std::piecewise_constant_distribution<_RealType>::param_type::param_type(_InputIteratorB, _InputIteratorB, _InputIteratorW) [with _InputIteratorB = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >; _InputIteratorW = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float> >; _RealType = double]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/random.h:4940:39:   required from ‘std::piecewise_constant_distribution<_RealType>::piecewise_constant_distribution(_InputIteratorB, _InputIteratorB, _InputIteratorW) [with _InputIteratorB = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >; _InputIteratorW = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float> >; _RealType = double]’
prog.cpp:17:64:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/random.tcc:2407:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<double>::push_back(std::basic_string<char>&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/random.tcc:2407:3: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/random.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/random:50,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:881:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = double; _Alloc = std::allocator<double>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = double]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:881:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const double&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:899:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = double; _Alloc = std::allocator<double>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = double]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:899:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘std::vector<double>::value_type&& {aka double&&}’
```

see?

> **no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string’** to
>   ‘std::vector::value_type&& {aka double&&}’

tells everything.